# Java retrieve generic method

Tags: java, generics, gson

I was trying to pass a client bean to genericResponsor class. but it was unable to retrieve the bean value.

**main class**

```
public Response searchClient(String json){
  //construct the receiver
  GenericReceiver<ClientBean> receiver = new GenericReceiver<ClientBean>();
  ClientBean clientbean = receiver.BeanReceiver(json, ClientBean.class);
  HeaderBean headerbean = receiver.HeaderReceiver(json);

  //process the data 
  ClientBean[] list = clientdao.searchclient(clientbean);

  //construct the responser
  GenericResponser<ClientBean> responser = new GenericResponser<ClientBean>();
  String Jsonbody = responsor.JsonResponse(clientbean, list, headerbean);
}
```

**The GenericResponser class** it seem like having problem to retrieve the clientBean.getCompanyId

```
public class GenericResponser <T>{
  public String JsonResponse( T bean,T[] list, HeaderBean headerbean) {
    String responsejson = ("{\"companyID\":\"" + bean.getCompanyId() + "\"}");
   }
}
```

During the debug I was able to see all the value of clientbean in GenericResponser but is not able to use and get the value. please help to get the value of clientbean.

**ClientBean class**

```
public class ClientBean {
    private String companyId;
    private String branchId;

 public ClientBean () {
  super();
  this.companyId    = "";
  this.branchId = "";
 }

  public java.lang.String getCompanyId() {
    return FormUtil.returnString(companyId);
  }

  public java.lang.String getBranchId() {
    return FormUtil.returnString(branchId);
  }

  public void setCompanyId(java.lang.String newCompanyId) {
    companyId = FormUtil.returnString(newCompanyId);
  }
  public void setBranchId(java.lang.String newBranchId) {
    branchId = FormUtil.returnString(newBranchId);
  }

}
```

The purpose for me to do this Generic is because it might be passing other bean into GenericResponser.

Comment: share the ClientBean class contents

Comment: Generics don't work that way. You cannot access methods on objects of which the type is not known at compile time.

Comment: Hi, JimmyB I'm not very familar with the Generics it must use the interface?